# ESC символ в Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

Как добавить 27 символ *ESC* в *Makefile*?

В текстовом виде у меня не получалось заставить правильно работать команды. Хотелось бы найти способ вставлять 27 код текстом. Если не получится, я бы предпочел вставку с помощью *mc*.

Пример, здесь вставляется цвет:

```
sed "s/error:/^[1;31merror:^[0m/g" dist/out;
```

^ - 27 символ.

Answer (score 1):

> Пример, здесь вставляется цвет: sed "s/error:/^[1;31merror:^[0m/g" dist/out;

если вам нужно вписать вместо символа `^` символ с кодом (десятичным) `27` или (шестнадцатиричным) `1b`, то в данном случае можно именно так и сделать, воспользовавшись нотацией `\xab` (где `ab` — шестнадцатиричный код):

```
sed "s/error:/\x1b[1;31merror:\x1b[0m/g" dist/out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте писать `\e[1;31` и т.д.

Comment: Это не срабатывает.

В принципе я записал в конец файла 27 символ с помощью echo -e "\e" >> ./Makefile и скопировал его в mc куда нужно. Вариант работает, но символы после ESC не соответствуют своему положению. Хочется вариант получше.

Comment: А так:

     \033[1:31m

Comment: Тоже нет. У вас нет лишнего Makefile под рукой? Было бы проще пробовать в нем.